# How to conditional format a column

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I am trying to create a conditional formatting rule for a column of dates. The column of dates is a list of move out dates. I would like dates that are within 30 days to be red, dates between 30 to 90 days to be yellow, and dates over 90 days to be green.

I would like the rows to be filled with the color as well. So if there is a move out date within the 30 days then the row would appear red and not just the cell.

How do I go about doing this? I'm also using Google Sheets as I have a chromebook.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Select your whole sheet (or all the rows you want the formatting on) and apply three conditional format rules for the whole range (in Google Sheets).

Assuming your date column is A, then
Custom formula #1 is: =$A1>today()+90
  Select green shading
Custom formula #2 is: =AND($A1today()+29)
  Select yellow shading
Custom formula #3 is: =$A1
  Select red shading